# How do I test Ember.run.later with Sinon?

Tags: ember.js, sinon

I have some Ember code that sets a timeout:

```
var MyObject = Ember.Object.extend({
  setFooToBarLater: function() {
    Ember.run.later(this, 'set', 'foo', 'bar', 500);
  }
});
```

I'd like to test that using Sinon's fake clock. Here's what I tried:

```
var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
var myObject = MyObject.create();
myObject.setFooToBarLater();
clock.tick(600);
expect(myObject.get('foo')).to.be('bar');
```

But the `expect` always runs before the `set`. I also tried wrapping the `clock.tick` in a run-loop:

```
Ember.run(clock, 'tick', 600);
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the Sinon tick to see if it eventually gets set? Ember.run.later does not give any guarantee on when exactly the callback will execute. It depends on what else is going on the Run loop.

Comment: @pradeek I increased it by a factor of 10 above what I expected. I suppose I could keep going!

Answer (score 4):

Beware that sinon.useFakeTimers (by default on) overrides the window.Date. That becomes an issue once you already have a scheduled Ember runloop and the useFakeTimers() is turned on. This is because Backburner (the Ember.js runloop implementation) setTimeout /core scheduling method/ tries hard to optimize calling window.setTimeout (look for `executeAt` in ember.js)

After going through the sinon source I made the following mod to let those two get along nicely ([gist](https://gist.github.com/opichals/9544091#file-sinon-usefaketimers-to-avoid-touching-window-date-js)). It instructs sinon not to touch the window.Date and also patches sinon.test() to wait few more ticks after the test body which allows scheduled timers to get executed and async codes

```
sinon._originalUseFakeTimers = sinon.useFakeTimers;
sinon.useFakeTimers = function() {
    // make sure we don't override window.Date used in
    // Backburner.setTimeout() to optimize window.setTimeout() call numbers
    return sinon._originalUseFakeTimers.apply(this, [new Date().getTime(), "setTimeout", "setInterval", "clearTimeout", "clearInterval"]);
};

sinon._originalTest = sinon.test;
sinon.test = function(callback) {
    return sinon._originalTest.call(this, function() {
        callback.apply(this, arguments);

        // wait for further runloops to finish (2s is the mocha timeout)
        this.clock.tick(2000);
    });
};
```

Comment: Great, this seems to be able to run Ember again, but I have to manually `tick` it, because I use sinon-timers 1.9 as standalone.

Sadly, moment.js does not accept the fake time anymore, returning the real one instead.

Comment: Hey @opichals, i tried your solution and failed. I submitted another question with more details and a demo. Can you please have a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782076/testing-how-to-assert-between-two-sequential-promises-run-laters-how-to-skip

Answer (score 3):

The answer appears to be not putting the `clock.tick` in a run-loop, but the call that actually invokes `Ember.run.later`. Thus, the following *does* work:

```
var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
var myObject = MyObject.create();
Ember.run(myObject, 'setFooToBarLater');
clock.tick(600);
expect(myObject.get('foo')).to.be('bar');
```

Comment: Hey @james-a-rosen, i tried your solution and failed. I submitted another question with more details and a demo. Can you please have a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782076/testing-how-to-assert-between-two-sequential-promises-run-laters-how-to-skip

Answer (score 1):

With ember 2.4.3 and sinon 0.5.0 seems to be fixed this kind of problems. `sinon.useFakeTimers()` works as expected with similar code on unit test:

```
const clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
assert.expect(1);
var MyObject = Ember.Object.extend({
    setFooToBarLater: function() {
      Ember.run.later(this, 'set', 'foo', 'bar', 500);
    }
  }), myObject = MyObject.create();
myObject.setFooToBarLater();
clock.tick(600);
assert.equal(myObject.get('foo'), 'bar');
clock.restore();
```