# Testing: how to assert between two sequential promises/run.laters? How to skip `run.later` waiting in tests?

Tags: ember.js, sinon

Here's a simple component:

```js
App.FooBarComponent = Ember.Component.extend({   
  tagName: "button",   
  status: "Ready",
  revertStatusPeriodMs: 2000,
  
  click: function() {
    this.set('status', 'Pending');
    
    // A fake ajax
    this.run()
      .then( function() {
        this.updateStatus('Finished');
      }.bind(this))
      .catch( function() {
        this.updateStatus('Error');
      }.bind(this));
  },
  
  run: function() {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise( function(resolve) {
      Ember.run.later( function() {
        resolve();
      }, 500);
    });
  },
  
  updateStatus: function(statusText) {
    this.set('status', statusText); 
    
    var periodMs = this.get('revertStatusPeriodMs') || 1000;
    
    Ember.run.later( function() {
      this.set('status', 'Ready');
    }.bind(this), periodMs);
  }
});
```

It does a simple thing: when clicked, it displays some text. Later replaces the text with another one. Even later, it reverts the text to the initial one.

The code works fine. My problem is that i'm unable to write a test for it.

```js
test('clicking the button should set the label', function(assert) {
  expect(4);
  
  visit('/');
  
  assert.equal( find('button').text().trim(), 'Ready', 'Should initially be "Ready"');
  
  andThen(function() {
    click('button');
    assert.equal( find('button').text().trim(), 'Pending', 'Should "Pending" right after click');
  });
  
  // This one fires too late!
  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal( find('button').text().trim(), 'Finished', 'Should become "Finished" after promise fulfills');
  });
  
  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal( find('button').text().trim(), 'Ready', 'Should eventually return to the "Ready" state');
  });
});
```

I have two problems:

1. I'm unable to test the `Finished` state. It seems that `andThen` waits for all promises and `run.later`s to finish, while i want to test an intermediate state. How do i run an assertion between two sequential promises/`run.later`s?
2. Times can be long, and tests can take forever to complete. I generally don't mind refactoring the code for better testability, but i refuse to adjust times in the app based on the environment (e. g. 2000 for dev/prod, 0 for test). Instead, i would like to use a timer mock or some other solution.

   I've tried Sinon and failed: when i mock the timer, `andThen` never returns. Neither of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896003/how-do-i-test-ember-run-later-with-sinon) solutions helped me.

JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fohava/2/edit?html,js,output (Sinon is included)

Answer (score 0):

None of your test code seems to use `asynch` – which would seem to be crucial since without anything to distinguish them, the last 2 tests will execute in the same tick (tests 3 & 4 can't both be true at the same time). I'm not familiar with QUnit, but I did find it's [`async` method](http://api.qunitjs.com/async/), which would seem to be pertinent. However when I tried calling `assert.async`, it blew up. I tried updating QUnit 1.17, still no dice.

So I don't have a solution for you. The problem, though, is that Ember will only execute both `andThen` tests once all the asynchronous execution has finished – this means that test 3 will never be true.

Comment: The `andThen` helper uses `assert.async`, i believe. As for the rest, i kinda knew thst already. But thanks for chiming in, Barney.

Comment: Well it's clear that Ember's built in helpers aren't fine-grained enough so they should probably go out in favour of explicit QUnit API calls... But again I'm just code golfing around an unfamiliar setup!

Answer (score 0):

I [did some code](https://github.com/jmurphyau/soq28782076) where I basically got it working but it seems really finicky and not something you would want to be do be doing..

I did this a few days ago but never replied because I wasn't happy with it - it doesn't give you enough control..

The reason I'm replying now however is because I've found a PR that may be of use to you: [PR 10463](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/10463)

I didn't look into too much detail but apparently it "allows custom async test helpers to pause execution by returning a promise"

I'm not sure what version of Ember you're using - but if you can hold out for this PR it may help you..